# NSOutlineView: exception when edit a NSTextFieldCell bound to a NSTreeController

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I get a crash when I edit a NSTextFieldCell (immediately after I click and the cursor starts to blink), in a NSOutlineView.

The table column is bound to the data source. The values are correctly displayed in the cell, the binding works, I get problems only when I edit the cell.

```
[theEditingColumn bind:@"value" myTreeController withKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrangedObjects.%@", metadata.columnBindingKeyPath] options:bindingOptions];
```

This is the exception I get. It seems that the `NSTextFieldCell` is setting/getting values from the `NSControllerTreeProxy` rather than the content of the NSTreeController.

```
-[_NSControllerTreeProxy _valueForKeyPath:ofObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ae0370
2015-07-16 11:20:55.008 [2647:735628] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x90e2bc63 __raiseError + 195
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x9488fa2a objc_exception_throw + 276
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x90e307c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x90d66758 ___forwarding___ + 1032
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x90d6632e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   AppKit                              0x9b9dd459 -[NSBinder _valueForKeyPath:ofObject:mode:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:] + 294
    6   AppKit                              0x9bd3e661 -[NSBinder valueForBinding:atIndex:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] + 461
    7   AppKit                              0x9c0c91a5 -[NSValueBinder _referenceBindingValueAtIndex:] + 56
    8   AppKit                              0x9bc382c7 -[_NSValueBinderPlugin editingHasBegun:] + 265
    9   AppKit                              0x9bc381ae -[NSValueBinder _startChanging] + 183
    10  AppKit                              0x9bc3802c -[NSTextValueBinder _startChanging] + 51
    11  AppKit                              0x9bc37ff4 -[NSValueBinder editorDidBeginEditing:] + 33
    12  AppKit                              0x9bc37fc4 -[_NSBindingAdaptor _editor:didChangeEditingState:bindingAdaptor:] + 166
    13  AppKit                              0x9bc37eec -[_NSBindingAdaptor editorDidBeginEditing:] + 218
    14  AppKit                              0x9c01ed24 -[NSTableView textShouldBeginEditing:] + 201
    15  AppKit                              0x9bb64be0 -[NSTextView(NSSharing) shouldChangeTextInRanges:replacementStrings:] + 310
    16  AppKit                              0x9bb64a9f -[NSTextView(NSSharing) shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:] + 121
    17  AppKit                              0x9c06c2c5 -[NSTextView(NSKeyBindingCommands) insertCompletion:forPartialWordRange:movement:isFinal:] + 513
    18  MyApp                               0x004de3d9 -[CBAutocompleteTextField insertCompletion:forPartialWordRange:movement:isFinal:] + 457
    19  AppKit                              0x9c070541 -[NSTextViewCompletionController _reflectSelection:] + 215
    20  AppKit                              0x9c0738b1 -[NSTextViewCompletionController tableViewSelectionDidChange:] + 41
    21  Foundation                          0x93eaa053 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke + 50
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x90de0c34 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x90cc0901 _CFXNotificationPost + 3713
    24  Foundation                          0x93e8b224 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 92
    25  Foundation                          0x93e9e772 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 56
    26  AppKit                              0x9ba1ce87 -[NSTableView _sendSelectionChangedNotificationForRows:columns:] + 169
    27  AppKit                              0x9b9e94ff -[NSTableView _enableSelectionPostingAndPost] + 410
    28  AppKit                              0x9ba1c619 -[NSTableView _doSelectIndexes:byExtendingSelection:indexType:funnelThroughSingleIndexVersion:] + 3171
    29  AppKit                              0x9ba1b9a3 -[NSTableView selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:] + 137
    30  AppKit                              0x9c072a7a -[NSTextViewCompletionController displayCompletions:indexOfSelectedItem:forPartialWordRange:originalString:atPoint:forTextView:] + 4794
    31  AppKit                              0x9c06c791 -[NSTextView(NSKeyBindingCommands) complete:] + 844
    32  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x9488d853 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    33  AppKit                              0x9bb7baba -[NSResponder doCommandBySelector:] + 91
    34  AppKit                              0x9bb7b93e -[NSTextView doCommandBySelector:] + 152
    35  AppKit                              0x9bb7b887 -[NSTextInputContext(NSInputContext_WithCompletion) doCommandBySelector:completionHandler:] + 114
    36  AppKit                              0x9bb7b80b -[NSTextInputContext doCommandBySelector:] + 61
    37  AppKit                              0x9bb7b6e3 -[NSTextInputContext _handleCommand:] + 96
    38  AppKit                              0x9bb610c3 -[NSKeyBindingManager(NSKeyBindingManager_MultiClients) interpretEventAsCommand:forClient:] + 2336
    39  AppKit                              0x9c1e4b2d __61-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:completionHandler:]_block_invoke1016 + 364
    40  AppKit                              0x9bb7b7ae __99-[NSTextInputContext tryHandleEvent_HasMarkedText_withDispatchCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:]_block_invoke + 34
    41  AppKit                              0x9bb7b779 __61-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_4 + 26
    42  AppKit                              0x9bb62f39 -[NSTextInputContext(NSInputContext_WithCompletion) hasMarkedTextWithCompletionHandler:] + 72
    43  AppKit                              0x9bb7b758 __61-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_3 + 104
    44  AppKit                              0x9bb741fc -[NSTextInputContext tryHandleEvent_HasMarkedText_withDispatchCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:] + 107
    45  AppKit                              0x9c1e48e3 __61-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:completionHandler:]_block_invoke1004 + 322
    46  AppKit                              0x9c1e42a3 __125-[NSTextInputContext tryTSMProcessRawKeyEvent:dispatchCondition:setupForDispatch:furtherCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:]_block_invoke + 33
    47  AppKit                              0x9c1e46da __61-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2994 + 46
    48  HIToolbox                           0x9288ebd9 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_5 + 86
    49  HIToolbox                           0x9288eb71 __TryKeyDownEventToTSMKeyEvent_WithContinuationHandler_block_invoke + 32
    50  HIToolbox                           0x9288eb44 __TSMKeyEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 26
    51  HIToolbox                           0x9288ead1 __utDeliverTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke_3 + 50
    52  HIToolbox                           0x9288d518 __SendUnicodeTextAEToUnicodeDoc_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke_2 + 57
    53  HIToolbox                           0x9288a37f __SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 72
    54  HIToolbox                           0x9288d4ca __SendEventToEventTargetWithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 25
    55  HIToolbox                           0x9288d49b ___ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec_block_invoke + 127
    56  AppKit                              0x9bb6f27c ___NSTSMEventHandler_block_invoke + 25
    57  AppKit                              0x9c1dd0a5 __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke195 + 2676
    58  AppKit                              0x9bb62fee __102-[NSTextInputContext tryHandleTSMEvent_HasMarkedText_withDispatchCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:]_block_invoke + 34
    59  AppKit                              0x9bb62fb2 __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_3 + 26
    60  AppKit                              0x9bb62f39 -[NSTextInputContext(NSInputContext_WithCompletion) hasMarkedTextWithCompletionHandler:] + 72
    61  AppKit                              0x9bb62ee1 __55-[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 104
    62  AppKit                              0x9bb62e3c -[NSTextInputContext tryHandleTSMEvent_HasMarkedText_withDispatchCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:] + 107
    63  AppKit                              0x9bb62ab5 -[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:completionHandler:] + 3364
    64  AppKit                              0x9bb61d2b _NSTSMEventHandler + 302
    65  HIToolbox                           0x929ed5a4 _Z22_InvokeEventHandlerUPPP25OpaqueEventHandlerCallRefP14OpaqueEventRefPvPFlS0_S2_S3_E + 36
    66  HIToolbox                           0x9282b681 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 2291
    67  HIToolbox                           0x9282a65c _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 402
    68  HIToolbox                           0x9282a4c3 SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 95
    69  HIToolbox                           0x92889ff9 SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 451
    70  HIToolbox                           0x9288a6ee __SendUnicodeTextAEToUnicodeDoc_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 569
    71  HIToolbox                           0x9288a49e __SendFilterTextEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 261
    72  HIToolbox                           0x9288a37f __SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 72
    73  HIToolbox                           0x9288a061 SendTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 555
    74  HIToolbox                           0x92889dfc SendFilterTextEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 283
    75  HIToolbox                           0x92889a04 SendUnicodeTextAEToUnicodeDoc_WithCompletionHandler + 398
    76  HIToolbox                           0x92889717 __utDeliverTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke_2 + 317
    77  HIToolbox                           0x92889592 __utDeliverTSMEvent_WithCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 465
    78  HIToolbox                           0x928893b8 TSMKeyEvent_WithCompletionHandler + 648
    79  HIToolbox                           0x928890d7 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_4 + 288
    80  HIToolbox                           0x92888f63 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_3 + 336
    81  HIToolbox                           0x92888cc9 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke_2 + 261
    82  HIToolbox                           0x92888ab7 __TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler_block_invoke + 255
    83  HIToolbox                           0x9286e413 TSMProcessRawKeyEventWithOptionsAndCompletionHandler + 3730
    84  AppKit                              0x9c1e46a4 __61-[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:completionHandler:]_block_invoke993 + 147
    85  AppKit                              0x9bb60652 -[NSTextInputContext tryTSMProcessRawKeyEvent:dispatchCondition:setupForDispatch:furtherCondition:dispatchWork:continuation:] + 129
    86  AppKit                              0x9bb6031d -[NSTextInputContext _handleEvent:options:completionHandler:] + 1708
    87  AppKit                              0x9bb5fc4e -[NSTextInputContext handleEvent:] + 128
    88  AppKit                              0x9bb5fb4b -[NSView interpretKeyEvents:] + 205
    89  AppKit                              0x9bb5f989 -[NSTextView keyDown:] + 686
    90  MyApp                               0x004de011 -[CBAutocompleteTextField keyDown:] + 385
    91  AppKit                              0x9c0e7f9b -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 8478
    92  AppKit                              0x9b9cb3ca -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 526
    93  AppKit                              0x9b9c79c4 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4765
    94  MyApp                                0x0004f2a2 -[CBApplication sendEvent:] + 370
    95  AppKit                              0x9b8e7bfc -[NSApplication run] + 1003
    96  AppKit                              0x9b85cfa0 NSApplicationMain + 2082
    97  MyApp                               0x000026fb main + 43
    98  MyApp                               0x00002605 start + 53
```

I guess the binding works well to display the values, but not for editing them?

**UPDATE**
I've added a symbolic breakpoint and I get the following:

```
po  *(id *)($esp + 4)
<NSTextValueBinder: 0xfe40720>{object: <NSTableColumn: 0xfe40180>   identifier: MovieReleaseYear, bindings: value=arrangedObjects.MovieReleaseYear}

p  *(SEL *)($esp + 8)
(SEL) $10 = "_valueForKeyPath:ofObject:mode:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:"

po  *(id *)($esp + 12)
arrangedObjects

po  *(id *)($esp + 16)
<CBTreeController: 0x39b4340>[object class: NSMutableDictionary]
```

Comment: @stevesliva Are you sure it's just a matter of asynchronous calls? I'm getting an "uncoregnized selector" exception: it's calling the getter on the proxy instead of his content.

Comment: No. It's probably not just that.  Just complicates debug.  When all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail... Just throwing it out there and happy to delete if fruitless for your case.

Comment: `_valueForKeyPath:ofObject:mode:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:` shows that you have an unknown key. Can you set a symbolic break point on it and have a look to the key path?

Comment: But in the other cases you do not get an exception? So add an exception break point.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad A practical question: I've stopped the execution on the symbolic breakpoint you suggest, but how do I check the path now? I have no variables in the variable list and I'm not sure what to print in the console.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I've solved the previous issue by adding another breakpoint just before that binding function was called

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad A screenshot to better describe the state of the debugger: http://cl.ly/image/1n2n0K193R3P

Comment: Well, you cannot print the argument using the parameter's name, because the code is compiled at Apple's. However, try `pinvocation` in the debugger.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Indeed, but I get error: 'pinvocation' is not a valid command.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad However I figured how to print more information from the Apple complied code. (I've added them to the question)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad However these are info that already knew. I guess the problem is this keyPath : arrangedObjects.MovieReleaseYear (arrangedObjects is just a proxy object). However I've defined such keyPath in the binding and it works correctly. I've tried others such as arrangedObjects.childNodes.MovieReleaseYear but it didn't work.

Comment: @Patrick - might be arrangedObjects.childNodes.representedObject.MovieReleaseYear if you stick childNodes in the keyPath.   NSTreeNodes, ya know.

Comment: @stevesliva Yes good point, but I've tried that and I get the same exception. Also, I don't get the values displayed in the table column either.

Comment: What is `CBTreeController`? What is `CBAutocompleteTextField`? You need to show the code for those. Is the latter a text view, text field, or text field cell? Is it the data cell of the column, a custom field editor for the cell, or some view outside of the outline view? If it's the data cell, does the problem go away if you use a standard `NSTextFieldCell` or otherwise stop using that class?

Comment: Also, the code line you showed is clearly not real; it wouldn't compile. What's the real line? What are the `bindingOptions`? When in the lifetime of the outline view are you setting that binding? Are you separately binding any of the bindings of the outline view itself? If so, what and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently stumbled upon the same problem as you. I am unsure if it is to late to help you, but I will still provide what fixed it for me.

I don't know your entire code, so I can't be sure if it is the same issue as you, but I was, too, trying to bind a column and edit it later, giving me the same crash.

It is quite simple in fact. I was binding the column before adding it to the Outline view like such :

```
[theEditingColumn bind:@"value" myTreeController withKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrangedObjects.%@", metadata.columnBindingKeyPath] options:bindingOptions];
[theOutlineView addTableColumn: theEditingColumn]
```

I can't give any explanation as to why this is the case, but switching it fixed it on my side :

```
[theOutlineView addTableColumn: theEditingColumn]
[theEditingColumn bind:@"value" myTreeController withKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrangedObjects.%@", metadata.columnBindingKeyPath] options:bindingOptions];
```

Comment: Wow. When I read your answer, I thought 'surely not', but there it was. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did not try it, but it could work with this line.

```
[theEditingColumn bind:@"value" myTreeController withKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrangedObjects.childNodes.representedObject.%@", metadata.columnBindingKeyPath] options:bindingOptions];
```